# How to start an Activity from the kernel module android

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, android-activity

I'm new to linux kernel. I'm trying to start an activity from the kernel module.
Here's what I have been trying to do :

```
static char *envp[] =  { 
  "HOME=/", 
  "PATH=/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin", NULL };
static char *argv[] = { "/system/bin/am", "start", "-a", "android.intent.action.MAIN", "-n", "com.whatsapp/.Conversation",  NULL};

call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, 1);
```

I don't see any problem inside my code. But the thing is that the activity is not being started. I just see this output in my logcat everytime :

```
 D/AndroidRuntime( 7417): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 7417): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 7417): CheckJNI is ON
E/dalvikvm( 7417): ERROR: must specify non-'.' bootclasspath
W/dalvikvm( 7417): CreateJavaVM failed: dvmClassStartup failed
E/AndroidRuntime( 7417): JNI_CreateJavaVM failed
```

I think the code should just work. I'm able t use `mkdir` command. It works without any problems. Where am I going wrong ?

**Edit** :

Adding `BOTTCLASSPATH` to `envp` works. But now I'm getting a strange problem.
When this function is executed with the app being initially closed, what happened was the app opened and in milliseconds of time it automatically closed with the following stacktrace :

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 4116): 
D/AndroidRuntime( 4116): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<<
D/AndroidRuntime( 4116): CheckJNI is OFF
D/dalvikvm( 4116): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 4116): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 4116): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 4116): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0
D/dalvikvm( 4116): No JNI_OnLoad found in libnativehelper.so 0x0, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4116): Note: class Landroid/app/ActivityManagerNative; has 179 unimplemented (abstract) methods
D/AndroidRuntime( 4116): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
I/ActivityManager(  653): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.whatsapp/.Conversations} from pid 4116
D/AndroidRuntime( 4116): Shutting down VM
I/ActivityManager(  652): Start proc com.android.browser for activity com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity: pid=4581 uid=10030 gids={50030, 3003, 1028, 1015, 1023}
D/ActivityThread( 4581): handleBindApplication:com.android.browser
D/ActivityThread( 4581): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
D/ActivityThread( 4581): setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
I/ActivityManager(  652): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{421d7768 u0 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL t1} time:347570
W/EventLoggerService( 2349): Unable to send logs Error code: 262146 | Unable to resolve host "www.google.com": No address associated with hostname
I/PowerManagerService(  652): Going to sleep due to screen timeout...
D/SurfaceFlinger(  210): Screen released, type=0 flinger=0x2a007450
```

When this command is executed with the app being in the paused state the app opens fine.

Comment: Keep in mind that the "proper" way to do this is to have some userspace daemon which registers with the kernel to be informed of things, and then accomplishes this kind of task when appropriate.

Comment: Your are still not providing anything meaningful about the the progress of the target Activity.  Write your own and have it log every lifecycle method, the setting of its content view, etc.

Comment: And meanwhile can you please point me to some docs about using this userspace daemaon.

Comment: AFAIK would have to write it from scratch.  Create a device you can do a blocking read on, and when you want to start something give it the name of what you want to start, it can do that and then block in another read.  Start the process in your init scripts and get it marked for protection from the oom killer like other system tasks are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your environment is incomplete.  `mkdir` is a simple native executable, but `am` is actually a shell script which loads `am.jar` into a dalvik virtual machine of some sort, and this appears to require quite a bit more setup.

Specifically, it seems to be complaining about the `BOOTCLASSPATH` environment variable being invalid.  Given that neither you nor the script seems to set it, it's probably empty.

`am` is designed to be used from the adb shell, so check what it would inherit from that by running:

```
adb shell 'echo $BOOTCLASSPATH'
```

And consider adding some or all of that to your environment.  There may be other things you need to set as well.

It might be cleaner to keep all of this userspace configuration detail out of the kernel by making your own shell script which does all of the setup: the additional steps as well as what the stock am script does.

Comment: Should I add a `BOOTCLASSATH` variable in my `envp` array ?

Comment: Either that, or make your own copy of the `am` script and export it there (much as the CLASSPATH is set there), to keep all this userspace detail out of the kernel.  You probably don't need everything that is on it either, but it may take experiment to find out what, so something you can more readily edit than the kernel would be handy.  Probably you can experimentally nullify the BOOTCLASSPATH in the adb shell and put it back bit by bit until the am command starts working again.

Comment: I'm still facing some issues with it. I've updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: There's not really any useful information in your added logcat - it looks pretty much like what you would see if you ran this am command from the adb shell.  In particular, your stack trace says nothing about the activity being closed - that VM shutdown message for (4116) refers to the VM in which `am` is running, not the activity, and we would expect that to shutdown as its work is done when the Intent is sent.

Comment: Beyond verifying you don't get the same behavior from the adb shell, you could look into what ActivityManager can discern about the sending process, and any way your "from out of nowhere" process might differ from an adb-started one.  Who owns it anyway?  Also, what state is the system in when this happens?  You could also try launching your own self-written Activity, and see if the issue is unique to this 3rd party app you are trying to start.

Comment: The activity i starting fine from the adb shell. And I tried it with Browser Activity and got the same results.

Comment: All I can really say is use a custom Activity loaded up with an outrageous amount of logging of everything - without collecting more information (you've provided no messages from the target Activity at all, yet you say it is presenting a UI so it clearly has the opportunity to create some) than you are providing this is going to be hard to solve.

Comment: I've updated my question by some more log lines. Can you please check if there is something to be guessed. I'm not getting the problem.
I'll also try with my own activity.

Comment: Hi Chris, It's really strange but my test app is working totally fine. and so far whatsapp and the browser app are not working as expected.